# How to set nginx wild card for location?

Tags: nginx

I have 20 different url path and want to route from nginx to service which allow only start with
/aaa/api/v1/ and wildcard after
example /aaa/api/v1/user
/aaa/api/v1/bbbb
/aaa/api/v1/customer
/aaa/api/v1/blablabla

I'm stuck with setup nginx default.conf for wild card for location like example below not working

```
location /aaa/devtest/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        rewrite /aaa/devtest/([^/]+) /aaa/api/v1/$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://aaa-api.namespace-dev:8080;
        proxy_redirect off;
  }
```

Any idea ?

Thank you.

Comment: What doesn't work? Show some access logs or error logs that demonstrate the problem you are trying to fix. You can enable the `rewrite_log` to help diagnose rewrite problems. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite_log).

Comment: I try to follow the link for rewrite_log but not success , However
I try this 

    location /aaa/dev/api/v1 {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://aaa-api-gateway.namespce-dev:8080/aaa/api/v1/;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
and it's work fine thanks